# MapReduce inverted index tree model

Tags: hadoop, tree, mapreduce, inverted-index

I want to make inverted index of very large text-based dataset using hadoop mapreduce. I want to save the inverted index files in tree based model.
Now I have a question about how to save these data in tree using mapreduce that I can retrieve them and search through.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your input and output? What you want to achieve?

Comment: for example imagine you have a btree and you want to serialize it to hdfs. I want to serialize an whole object to hdfs.

Comment: Have you checked Solr/Lucene option for doing this ?